# How to find probabilities at the end of observations period?

Tags: probability, predictive-models, conditional-probability, observational-study

I am collecting stats results for 15 consecutive days for network lines and the outcome for a line could be: 
1 **No problem** 
2 **Problem of type A** 
3 **Problem of type B**
What is the best attack for this problem? 
Bear in mind that we have to reevaluate the probabilities for every line every day. 
A solution in terms of probabilities at the end of this period is required. 
I want to find out what are the probabilities for a line to be defective or better if it in category 1 or 2 or 3 two months after this period of 15 days. 
So, every day for every line we have an event: **1 No problem** or **2 Problem of type A** or **3 Problem of type B**. Would it be better to consider this as a binomial problem? Line good or no good.

Comment: "A solution in terms of probabilities at the end of a period for a line being in category 1 or 2 or 3 is required." What does this mean, exactly: the probability for it being in a category in an arbitrary day, in the end of the period, or something else?

Comment: During the period of 15 days a line could be some days healthy and some days defective. I want to know for a given line what will hapen after this period of 15 days. I mean, at the end of the period I want to find out the probabilities of a line line to be defective for some time after 2 months for example.

Comment: You ask for the best attack of a problem, but you did not describe the problem. (the fact that you are collecting data of network lines is not a problem)

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. However, a multinomial distribution is the generalization of the Binomial distr. You might want to read about that.